# Statically passing arrays to a Vue component

Tags: vue.js

I need to statically pass an array to my `Vue` component, called `ajax-table`. I can't seem to find a way to do it, so I came up with this:

```
<ajax-table
    header-names="Code, Name, Description, Type"
    field-names="code, name, description, major_type">
</ajax-table>
```

Inside the component, I do this:

```
export default {

    props: [
        'headerNames',
        'fieldNames'
    ],

    data: function () {

        return {
            columnHeaders: [],
            columnFields: []
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.columnHeaders = this.headerNames.split(",").map(x => x.trim());
        this.columnFields = this.fieldNames.split(",").map(x => x.trim());
    }
}
```

Now, `columnHeaders` and `columnFields` contain the `header-names` and `field-names` that I passed statically to the component.

My question: 
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to directly pass the array to props using `v-bind:` directive or `:` for short:

```
<ajax-table
    :header-names="['Code', 'Name', 'Description', 'Type']"
    :field-names="['code', 'name', 'description', 'major_type']">
</ajax-table>
```

Now props `headerNames` and `fieldNames` are arrays, which you can use in the component.

Comment: It works! So, the array expression in double quotes is only evaluated if I use `v-bind` and not if I pass it statically?

Comment: Yep. When using `v-bind`, the value passed in is evaluated as javascript object, so you can pass arrays or other valid javascript object. Without it, it's simple html, so the value is considered as a string.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.